# multi deimensional array of cities

Tags: php, arrays

I have multiple ids (0, 1, 2). How do I get the city name of the respective id from following array?

Here is an example array:

```
$cities_array = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'city' => 'Sant JuliÃ  de LÃ²ria',
    'region' => '06',
    'country' => 'AD',
    'latitude' => '42.46372',
    'longitude' => '1.49129',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'city' => 'Pas de la Casa',
    'region' => '03',
    'country' => 'AD',
    'latitude' => '42.54277',
    'longitude' => '1.73361',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'city' => 'Ordino',
    'region' => '05',
    'country' => 'AD',
    'latitude' => '42.55623',
    'longitude' => '1.53319',
  )
);
```

Comment: echo $cities_array[1]['city'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just acceed to the city name by using

```
$cities_array[your_id]['city'];
```

Comment: if  i don't have ID and want to access the city name using country .
From above example i have country name "AD", how can i get its cities ?

Comment: Didn't see your comment, I'm sorry!

You'll need to loop over the array and juste create a flat one containing the cities. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So you need to access php associative array using the following code

```
 foreach($cities_array as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value['city'].' '.$value['region'].' '.$value['country'].' '.$value['latitude'].' '.$value['longitude']."<br>";
}
```

And if you are not displaying in browser use the following code

```
foreach($cities_array as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value['city'].' '.$value['region'].' '.$value['country'].' '.$value['latitude'].' '.$value['longitude']."\r\n";
}
```

if you search for a particular id then the task is more easy

```
foreach($cities_array as $key => $value)
{
if($key==id)
    echo $value['city'].' '.$value['region'].' '.$value['country'].' '.$value['latitude'].' '.$value['longitude']."\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the id, you can access your city names directly:

```
echo $cities_array[0]['city]; // Sant JuliÃ  de LÃ²ria
echo $cities_array[1]['city]; // Pas de la Casa
echo $cities_array[2]['city]; // Ordino
```

Comment: if  i don't have ID and want to access the city name using country .
From above example i have country name "AD", how can i get its cities ?